# Problema de conexão java + postegre no heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, heroku

Tentando conectar o java com o banco do heroku (postgre), já conferi a url várias vezes e não possui erros. Não estou usando hibernate. Pelo pgadmin consigo inserir no banco normalmente. Como consertar esse erro? Devo realizar alguma mudança no pom.xml?

```
private static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-83-27-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1o8bcicho5jj?user=usuario&password=senha&sslmode=require";
        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:postgresql://ec2...

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Baixou e adicionou o driver do postgree para JDBC no classpath do projeto?

Comment: Mesmo que eu não vá executar localmente preciso do driver?

Comment: SEMPRE! O driver é uma especie de tradutor, sem ele, o banco não vai entender nenhum comando que você passar, por isso que surge o erro.

Comment: Editei com uma parte do pom, o driver seria aquilo?

Comment: Ou devo baixar e colocar no classpath msm?